# Overriding class method via a wrapper class

Tags: c#, inheritance, architecture, polymorphism

I'm trying to come up with a very neat way to alter an existing class. I'll try to explain what I came up with using this example;

```
abstract class AbstractX
{
    public abstract string X();
    protected internal abstract int Y();
}

// Execute all methods on another instance of AbstractX
// This is why the method(s) are 'protected *internal*'
class WrappedX : AbstractX
{
    AbstractX _orig;
    public WrappedX(AbstractX orig)
    {
        _orig = orig;
    }

    public override string X()
    {
        return _orig.X();
    }
    protected internal override int Y()
    {
        return _orig.Y();
    }
}

// The AbstractX implementation I start with
class DefaultX : AbstractX
{
    public override string X()
    {
        // do stuff

        // call Y, note that this would never call Y in WrappedX
        var y = Y();

        return y.ToString();
    }
    protected internal override int Y()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

// The AbstractX implementation that should be able to alter *any* other AbstractX class
class AlteredX : WrappedX
{
    public AlteredX(AbstractX orig)
        :base(orig)
    {
    }

    protected internal override int Y()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sweet, this can be added to any AbstractX instance!");

        return base.Y();
    }
}
```

Right, so the way I intend to use this is;

```
AbstractX x = new DefaultX();
x = new AlteredX(x);
Console.WriteLine(x.X()); // Should output 2 lines
```

Or to step away from the abstract example for a second and make it more concrete (should be self-explanatory);

```
FileWriterAbstract writer = new FileWriterDefault("path/to/file.ext");
writer = new FileWriterSplit(writer, "100MB");
writer = new FileWriterLogged(writer, "path/to/log.log");
writer.Write("Hello");
```

But (back to the abstract example) this isn't going to work. The moment `AlteredX.X()` is called (which isn't overridden) it goes to `WrappedX.X()`, which of course runs `DefaultX.X()` which uses it's *own* `Y()` method, and not the one I defined in `AlteredX.` It doesn't even know it exists.

I'm hoping it's obvious why I want this to work, but I'll explain further to make sure;

If I don't use `WrappedX` to created `AlteredX,` AlteredX will not be 'applyable' to *any* AbstractX instance, 
thus making something like the `FileWriter` above impossible. Instead of;

```
FileWriterAbstract
FileWriterDefault : FileWriterAbstract
FileWriterWrap : FileWriterAbstract
FileWriterSplit : FileWriterWrap
FileWriterLogged : FileWriterWrap
```

It would become;

```
FileWriterAbstract
FileWriterDefault : FileWriterAbstract
FileWriterSplit : FileWriterDefault
// Implement Logged twice because we may want to use it with or without Split
FileWriterLogged : FileWriterDefault
FileWriterLoggedSplit : FileWriterSplit
```

And if I then created a new one, I'd have to implement it 4 times because I'd want it usable with;

```
Default
Split
Logged
Split+Logged
```

And so on...

So with that in mind, what's the best way to achieve this? The best I could come up with (untested) is;

```
class DefaultX : AbstractX
{
    protected internal override Func<string> xf { get; set; }
    protected internal override Func<int> yf { get; set; }

    public DefaultX()
    {
        xf = XDefault;
        yf = YDefault;
    }

    public override string X()
    {
        return xf();
    }

    protected override int Y()
    {
        return yf();
    }

    string XDefault()
    {
        var y = Y();

        return y.ToString();
    }

    int YDefault()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class AlteredX : WrappedX
{
    Func<int> _yfOrig { get; set; }

    public AlteredX()
    {
        // I'm assuming this class member doesn't get overwritten when I set
        // base.yf in the line below.
        _yfOrig = base.yf;

        base.yf = YAltered;
    }

    private int YAltered()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sweet, this can be added to any AbstractX instance!");

        return yfOrig();
    }
}
```

Even if this does work, it seems really messy... does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What you've come up with looks like the Decorator pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: @Alireza I know, that doesn't change the fact that I'm looking for a solution to the problem.

Comment: @tvanfosson Yeah, looks like it. That wiki page only shows examples that don't try to override specific methods that are called by the public methods though, so my question stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to defer all of the internal operations to a separate, perhaps, internal utility class and provide a way for the wrapping classes to replace the implementation of the utility class.  Note: this example requires any concrete, non-wrapping class to implement the utility class.  A wrapper class may or may not choose to wrap the utility class.  The key here is that the getter/setter for the utilities class in the base (abstract) class doesn't allow it to be overridden, thus every inheriting class uses the utility class as defined by it's constructor.  If it chooses not to create it's own utilities, it defaults to that of the class it's wrapping - eventually making it all the way back to the concrete, non-wrapped composition root class if need be.

NOTE: this is very complex and I would avoid doing it.  If possible use the standard decorator and only rely on public interface methods of the wrapped class.  Also, the utility classes need not be inner classes.  They could be injected via the constructor which might make it a bit cleaner.  Then you would explicitly use the Decorator pattern on the utilities as well.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string X();
}

public abstract class AbstractFoo : IFoo
{
    public abstract string X();

    protected internal Footilities Utilities { get; set; }

    protected internal abstract class Footilities
    {
        public abstract int Y();
    }
}

public class DefaultFoo : AbstractFoo
{
    public DefaultFoo()
    {
        Utilities = new DefaultFootilities();
    }

    public override string X()
    {
        var y = Utilities.Y();

        return y.ToString();
    }

    protected internal class DefaultFootilities : Footilities
    {
        public override int Y()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractWrappedFoo : AbstractFoo
{
    protected readonly AbstractFoo Foo;

    public AbstractWrappedFoo(AbstractFoo foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }

    public override string X()
    {
        return Foo.X();
    }
}

public class LoggedFoo : AbstractWrappedFoo
{
    public LoggedFoo(AbstractFoo foo)
        : base(foo)
    {
        Foo.Utilities = new LoggedUtilities(Foo.Utilities);
    }

    public override string X()
    {
        return Foo.X();
    }


    protected internal class LoggedUtilities : Footilities
    {
        private readonly Footilities _utilities;

        public LoggedUtilities(Footilities utilities)
        {
            _utilities = utilities;
        }

        public override int Y()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sweet");
            return _utilities.Y();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AbstractFoo foo = new LoggedFoo(new DefaultFoo());

        Console.WriteLine(foo.X());
    }
}
```

Produces

```
Sweet!
1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In many ways, this is the same as what I put at the end of my question, except you are using a class rather than an Action/Func. I guess that means there's no better alternative, so I'll  stick with it.

Comment: @natli Both seem overly complex, but it's hard to give you better advice given an abstract problem. I think I'd try to remove the reuse of the internal/protected methods. Hard to say how without seeing what you're doing in the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up composition with inheritance.

When you call x.X() on an AlteredX object, the object calls X method of it's base object (WrappedX). The base object itself calls an object of type DefaultX which it has already wrapped. Now the Y method is called on an an object of DefaultX (_orig). You expect _orig knows there is something overriden in the caller of the caller! But how?

In this chain of call I don't see any point where overriding the method Y is involved.

Comment: Did you read the question all the way through? I already know this is the problem, but I am still looking for a solution to do what I'm trying to do.